# How to read off the tangent map of a map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Maybe a silly question, but:
Given a map, e.g. 
$$
 \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3
\\
(u,v) \mapsto (\cos u \sin v, \sin u \sin v, (1-2\cos^2 v) cosv)\,,
$$
how can I quickly read off the tangent map of it?

Comment: Doesn't this question make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly? You write down the $3\times 2$ matrix whose $ij$-entry is the partial derivative of the $i$th component function with respect to the $j$th variable. (In this regard, it might be helpful to write the mapping as a column vector.)

Comment: Thanks. But I confuse the definition of tangent map. So, if we call the map $\phi: M \rightarrow N$, we then have $T_p \phi (v) (g) = v(g \circ \phi)$, where $v$ is a vector field on $TM$ and $g$ is a function. I cannot figure out how one can calculate the tangent map by means of this definition.

Comment: If $\phi(x)=y$ in our case, take $g=y_i$ and $v=\partial/\partial x_i$.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to do that. But, how should I write the map $T_p \phi: T_p \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow T_p\mathbb{R}^3$ correctly? It takes a point and a vector and maps it to what?

Comment: Is this correct? $(p,\partial/\partial x^i)\mapsto T_p\phi(\partial/\partial x^i)(y^j)$? Which is equal to the matrix you said already.

Comment: Yes, precisely. :)